# Count how many characters

Tags: c#

I usually never use char so sorry if it seems a noob question. I'm doing a Crypter, and wanted to do "if there's at least 4 differents char, then crypt, else don't crypt and return error"

Actual Code:

```
string msg = Console.ReadLine();
char[] msgToChar = msg.ToCharArray();
if(here is the problem)
{
Console.WriteLine("Crypted message: " + Crypt(msg.ToUpper()));
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Please enter at least 4 differentes characters.");
}
```

Comment: You could use `GroupBy`.

Comment: `Distinct` and `Count` would be easier to read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this to get the distinct count of characters.

```
msgToChar.Distinct().Count()
```

So your if would be something like

```
if (msgToChar.Distinct().Count() >= 4)
```